# VIewPager2 using wrap_content instead of match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager2

I have a horizontal scrolling view pager. I set child items width to `match_parent`. But im getting them `wrap_content` instead. This view should be centred by gravity but parent's FrameLayout is cropped to child's width
Items code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/exo_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:use_controller="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sound"
        android:layout_width="26dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="13dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_sound_off_active" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: This view should be centred]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be related to the resolution of the video you being played, rather than the view matching its parent's width.